# "Frit" as dialect for "frightened" - which dialects, especially as simple past?

Tags: verbs, british-english, dialects

Out walking the other day I came across a lovely West-Country-ism from a local walking her dog - *frit*, meaning frightened, in "you frit him" (referring to a startled dog). The speaker sounded local (Bristol / Gloucestershire).

[Oxford online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/frit) gives it as an adjective, with the origin: "Early 19th century: dialect past participle of fright." but I'm interested more in the verb use, in particular, in which dialects it is or was used.

A related discussion at [WordReference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/frit-frightened.815029/) gives some scattered examples of the use as an adjective, including one in which the then Prime Minister Margaret Thatcher used it in a list of synonyms for "afraid".  Examples as a verb are harder to find

Comment: As a BrE native speaker, I don't associate **frit** with any regional dialect.

Comment: @WeatherVane Do you mean that you don't recognise 'frit' as being part of any dialect you know or that you think 'frit' is universal in British English?

Comment: @BoldBen I mean that I think it is colloquial (as mentioned by @TaliesinMerlin) rather than a regional dialect.

Comment: @WeatherVane However the West Country example given by the OP uses "frit" as a transitive verb ("you frit him"). This is different from the Derbyshire, Nottinghamshire and Lincolnshire usages with which I am familiar where "frit" is always intransitive (like Mrs Thatcher's "you're frit"). In the dialects with which I am familiar the transitive version would be variations on "Tha's frittened him".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While dictionaries tend to describe *frit* as a *dialect-based usage*, its usage as a past participle is widespread enough that *register* (it being colloquial) is more important to its use than place. The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/74793) (note: paywall) notes the dialect usage, but not which dialects:

> Dialect and colloquial past participle of fright v. 2a.

...

> (fright v. 2a.) transitive. To affect with fright; to scare, terrify. Now rare exc. poetic and dialect; in ordinary language its place has been taken by frighten.

A selection of the quotes illustrates that the shortened form *frit* goes back to the 19th century, with a possible breadth of sources:

> 1821   J. Clare Village Minstrel II. 196   The coy hare squats nestling in the corn, **Frit** at the bow'd ear tott'ring o'er her head.
>
> 1908   D. H. Lawrence Let. 31 Dec. (1962) I. 44   The woman is..a wee bit **frit**.
>
> 1960   Oxf. Mail 4 Aug. 1/5   When I heard he was dead I got **frit**.
>
> 1970   New Society 19 Nov. 897/3   I was **frit**, cold and bored.

Most of these uses treat *frit* as a past participle.

The [English Dialect Dictionary Online 3.0](http://eddonline-proj.uibk.ac.at/edd/) (an adaptation of a late 19th century/ early 20th century dialect dictionary) provides more information in its entry for *fright, v. and sb.*. For the past participle *frit*, the following entries and dialect areas are mentioned (I expand the dialect area abbreviations):

> (6) **Nottingham**. He war always frit in the dark (L.C.M.); Harrod Hist. Mansfield (1801) 53.
>
> **South Nottingham**. A were a bit frit at the noise (J.P.K.). **Lincoln**. (J.C.W.);
>
> **Lincoln**.1 **North Lincoln**. He was to be frit wi' nowt, Peacock Taales (1890) 2nd S.
>    121. **South Lincoln**. (T.H.R.), Lei.1
>
> **Northampton**. Frit at the bow'd ear tott'ring
>    o'er her head, Clare Poems (1821) II. 196;
>
> **Northampton**.1 I was frit to
>    death;
>
> **Northampton**.2 He was soon frit, warnt he?
>
> **Warwick**.24, **South Warwick**.1
>    **Hereford**.2 Is her frit?
>
> **Oxford**. Frit to death (G.P.).
>
> **Bedford**. Being ‘sore
>    afraid’ was explained in the Sunday-school to signify being
>    ‘uncommon frit’ (J.W.B.).
>
> **Hertford**. (J.W.),
>
> **Huntingdon**. (T.P.F.)
>
> **Suffolk**. He
>    fare wholly frit (C.T.).
>
> **Sussex**.1 I was quite frit to see him so near
>    the water.
>
> **Hampshire**. N. & Q. (1854) 1st S. x. 120;
>
> **Hampshire**.1, **East Devonshire**.

So the past participle form crops up in many places, from Nottingham to Sussex to Devonshire. In addition, the *EDD Online* notes that the basic form *frit* is present in Scotland and the preterite form *frit* occurs in Nottingham, Lincoln, and as far south as Warwick and Leicester. So the word seems dialect-based in a broad sense. For example, regional dialects of British English uses *frit* but American English does not.

Returning to Oxford Dictionaries, [an article on Margaret Thatcher's use of the word *frit*](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/04/10/margaretthatcher/) confirms that the word is "regional" but not locked down to a single place like Lincolnshire:

> In the early 1980s, Mrs Thatcher accused the Labour politician Denis Healey of being “frit”, corresponding with modern day “frightened”. It was widely reported, at the time, that she had employed a Lincolnshire dialect word, demonstrating her Grantham roots. This wasn’t quite true – “frit” is used much more widely in English regional use that just Lincolnshire.

Indeed, her opponents seize upon the informal register of the term:

> The term was seized upon by her political opponents and cries of “frit”, “is she frit?”, and even “Madame Frit” could be heard in the House of Commons for a good few years afterward.

Comment: "Dialect" would appear to mean "not London" in this case then (I've also seen citations from Yorkshire).

Comment: More or less. :) Not London and not RP.